# Why am i getting an error Invalid expression term 'if'?

Tags: c#

A program to calculate the get the grade of 10 students
the program is below.

```
  Console.WriteLine(" Enter your scoreCA: ");
            scoreCA = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(" Enter your scoreExam: ");
            scoreExam = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            scoreTotal[i] = scoreExam + scoreCA;
            for (i=0, i<10, i++;
            scoreTotal[i] = scoreExam + scoreCA ;    
        if (scoreTotal < 0 || scoreTotal > 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("invalid");
        }
        else if  (scoreTotal <= 100 && scoreTotal > 69)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your Grade is A");
        }

        else if (scoreTotal < 70 && scoreTotal > 59)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your grade is B");
        }

        else if (scoreTotal < 60 && scoreTotal > 59)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your grade is C");
        }

        else if (scoreTotal < 50 && scoreTotal > 44)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your grade is D");
        }

        else (scoreTotal < 45 && scoreTotal >= 0);
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your grade is F");
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: The compiler usually gives you a line number. Mind helping us out by giving the full error details?

Comment: did you write this your self?

Comment: Also, your `for` statement on line 6 is missing a right parenthesis.

Comment: where is your last bracket?

Comment: you need to add `if` after the latest `else` and delete the `;` in the end of this line

Comment: Yes i wrote it myself @M.kazemAkhgary

Comment: the error is on line 19 @itsme86

Comment: Ayo, your question, was not really even a proper question. It was pretty much: here, this is broke, fix it for me.

Comment: @Ayo Line 19 you say. Do you see line numbers here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop is missing a closing parenthesis so it's not expecting to encounter an `if` statement mid-loop expression.

---

### Edit - Here's a properly formatted code block.

```
Console.WriteLine(" Enter your scoreCA: ");
double scoreCA = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine(" Enter your scoreExam: ");
double scoreExam = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
double[] scoreTotal;
for (i=0, i<10, i++)
{
    scoreTotal[i] = scoreExam + scoreCA;
    if (scoreTotal < 0 || scoreTotal > 100)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("invalid");
    }
    else if (scoreTotal <= 100 && scoreTotal > 69)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your Grade is A");
    }
    else if (scoreTotal < 70 && scoreTotal > 59)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your grade is B");
    }
    else if (scoreTotal < 60 && scoreTotal > 59)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your grade is C");
    }
    else if (scoreTotal < 50 && scoreTotal > 44)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your grade is D");
    }
    else (scoreTotal < 45 && scoreTotal >= 0);
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your grade is F");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: PS - Heed the advice given in comments to make better questions in the future, but don't let the pedants scare you away. They sometimes get nitpicky and can even get a little condescending. Welcome to the community! This isn't bad for your first question :)

Comment: how do i get the closing parenthesis? @chev

Comment: Change this `for (i=0, i<10, i++;` to this `for (i=0, i<10, i++)`.

Comment: thanks a lot @chev

Comment: np, good luck with your learning! We were all there once :)

Comment: PSS - Don't forget to accept the answer when you can if it helped you :)

Comment: i have changed my for to for(i=0, i<10, i++) but it is giving 3 errors now. 1) ; expected in line 17 2) ; expected in line 17 3) ) expected in line 18

Comment: Sounds like you have a few syntax issues. Keep following what the errors say. Make sure your opening and closing curly braces are in the right places. For loops can work with one line without the curly braces but it's good practice to include the braces for readability. If you need multiple lines to loop then you ***have*** to include the curly braces around the statements you intend to be part of the for loop. See my edited answer for a properly formatted code block.

Comment: it is still giving me errors. have you tried running it?

Comment: No, I'm not even completely sure what your code is trying to do. As others have said this site isn't for writing your code for you. I'm just trying to help fix your syntax issues.

Comment: sorry i get. Am trying to get the grade of 10 students by inputing their scores for ca and exam. @chev